# New posts on my app are not showing but the old posts are. React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I recently added redux to my social media app. The old posts(The ones that were there before I added redux) are getting rendered correctly but when I try to add a new post it just shows a blank card. I checked the redux store and everything and the data is getting stored correctly.
[This is the redux state before I add a new post. You can see the old posts(The ones that were there before I added redux to my project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W68aF.png)

[This is after I add a new post. The data is correctly added to the redux store but all it shows is a blank card on the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukz9r.png)

This is the code responsible for rendering the posts.

```
class PostComment extends Component{

state={
    showNewPost: false
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchPosts();
}

DeleteCommentHandler = (index) => {
   this.props.onDeletePost(index);
}

ShowFunction = () => {
    this.setState({showNewPost: !this.state.showNewPost})
}

render() {
    let cardData = <center> <Spinner/></center>

    if(!this.props.loading){
   cardData = <div className="posts">  
   {/*add font awesome search icon*/}   
   <div className="topSection">
       <input type="text" className="Searchbar" placeholder="Search for people, topics or keywords..."/>
       <Button className="btn btn-primary">Search</Button>
       <NewPost/>
       </div>

{this.props.data.reverse().map((res) => (    
        <div>
                   <Card
                   key={res.id}
                   className="Cards"
                   >

                  <Card.Body
                  className="container">
                       <h6>
                       @ANONYMOUS
                        </h6>
                       <Card.Text>
                        {res.Comment} 
                       </Card.Text>
                        
                        <div>
                            <center>
                        <img src={res.ImageUrl} width = "680px" height="390px" />
                            </center>
                            </div>
                 

                <br/>
                 <Button className="btn btn-danger" 
                 style={{float:"right", width:"35px", height:"35px", borderRadius:"5px"}}
                 onClick={() => this.DeleteCommentHandler(res.id)}>
                     
                     <center>
                     <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} style={{width:"11px"}}/>
                     </center>

                     </Button> 
                   </Card.Body>
                   <Card.Footer style={{position:"relative", marginTop:"20px"}}>
                       {res.Date}
                   </Card.Footer>
                   </Card>                                
                   
           </div>
       )
)}
</div>
}

return(

<div> 
    {cardData}
 </div>

);
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        data: state.Data,
        loading: state.loading
    };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onFetchPosts: () => dispatch(actions.FetchPost()),
        onDeletePost: (postId) => dispatch(actions.DeletePost(postId))
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostComment);
```

This is the action.js file

```
import axios from '../../axios-comments';
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';


export const NewPostSuccess = (id, postData) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.New_Post_Success,
        payload: {
            data: postData,
            id: id
        }
    }
}

export const NewPostError = (error) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.New_Post_Error,
        error: error
    }
}


export const NewPost = (postData) => {
  
          return (dispatch) => {
           axios.post('/Data.json', postData)
           .then(response => {
               console.log(response.data);
               dispatch(NewPostSuccess(response.data.name, postData));
           })
           .catch(error => {
               dispatch(NewPostError(error));
           })
          }
  }

  
  export const DeletePostSuccess = (id) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.Delete_Post_Success,
        index: id
    }
}


  export const DeletePost = (index) => {
      
        return (dispatch) => {
    axios.delete('/Data/'+ index + '.json')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        dispatch(DeletePostSuccess(index))   
    })
            }
  }


  export const FetchPostStart = () => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.Fetch_Post_Start
    };
};

  export const FetchPostSuccess = (fetchedData) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.Fetch_Post_Success,
        payload: fetchedData
    }
}

export const FetchPostError = (error) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.Fetch_Post_Error,
        error: error
    }
}
  
export const FetchPost = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(FetchPostStart());
        axios.get('/Data.json')
        .then(response => {
           const fetchedData = [];
    
           for(let key in response.data){
                   fetchedData.push({
                   ...response.data[key],
                   id: key
               });
           }
           dispatch(FetchPostSuccess(fetchedData));
        })
    
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(FetchPostError(error));
        });
    }
}
```

This is the reducer function

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    Data: [],
    loading: false
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => { 
    switch(action.type){
     
        case actionTypes.New_Post_Error: 
        return {
          ...state,
          loading:false
        }

        case actionTypes.New_Post_Success: 
        return {
         ...state,
         loading: false,
         Data: [...state.Data, action.payload.data]
        }

        case actionTypes.Delete_Post_Success:
          const selectedComment = state.Data.filter(res => res.id !== action.index);  
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            Data: selectedComment
          }

        case actionTypes.Fetch_Post_Start: 
        return {
            ...state,
            loading:true
          }

        case actionTypes.Fetch_Post_Error: 
        return {
            ...state,
            loading:false
          }
  
          case actionTypes.Fetch_Post_Success: 
          return {
           ...state,
           loading: false,
           Data: action.payload
          }

     default: return state;
 }
}

export default reducer;
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Are you saying that your `FetchPost` action isn't fetching and storing new posts in state? Can you share your action and reducer code, and how you configure your redux store?

Comment: @DrewReese Hey, I added the action and reducer function and some more details. The problem could be in FetchPost, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, yes, you populate `state.Data`, but notice in the old objects that your property keys are PascalCased instead of camelCased like the newly added post object.

[image] vs [image]

In your code you are mapping `res.Comment` and `res.ImageUrl`!

While I highly encourage you to adopt a more standard pascalCased naming convention (*likely starting from the source in your JSON data!!*), you can update the new post success reducer case to maintain the state invariant.

```
case actionTypes.New_Post_Success: 
  const { comment: Comment, imageUrl: ImageUrl } = action.payload.data;
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    Data: [
      ...state.Data,
      { Comment, ImageUrl },
    ],
  }
```